# MySQL DB update 2 values: 1 increase & 1 decrease

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in my database called `member` within this table are the fields 'personID`&`balance`.

If a user 1 has a balance of 20.00 and wishes to send 10.00 to user 2 what is the best way to reduce user 1's balance and update user 2's balance?

Any help/advice would be great!

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

CODE:

```
 $accountfrom=$_POST[accountfrom];
 $accountto=$_POST[accountto];
 $amount=$_POST[amount]; 
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","cl49-XXX","XXX");
if (!$con) 
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

mysql_select_db("cl49-XXX", $con)or die( "Unable to select database");


$result = mysql_query("UPDATE member
SET balance = IF(personID = $acountfrom, balance-$amount, balance+$amount)
WHERE personID IN ($accountfrom, $accountto)")
 or die(mysql_error());
```

RESULT:

> 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' balance-100.00, balance+100.00) WHERE personID IN (84587745 ,
>   98554130)' at line 2'

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE member
SET balance = IF(personID = 1, balance-10, balance+10)
WHERE personID IN (1, 2)
```

To limit the transfer to the sender's balance:

```
UPDATE member m1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEAST(10, balance) transfer
      FROM member
      WHERE personID = 1) m2
SET m1.balance = IF(personID = 1, balance - transfer, balance + transfer)
WHERE personID in (1, 2)
```

Comment: You misspelled `$accountfrom`, you left out one of the `c`s.

Comment: If you didn't get an `Undefined variable` warning, you need to increase your error reporting level.

Comment: Thanks for this. Now got it working. If the user sending funds only has a balance of 100 how do i stop them sending more? (e.g 110)?

Comment: @Barmar [`hello`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2942928/hello) => aka [`shane`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2564653/shane) aka => "vampire" - thought you might like/want to know ;-)